# SVProgressHUD Can't show the status

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, svprogresshud

When I use `[SVProgressHUD show]`, delay 2 seconds, then use `[SVProgressHUD dismiss]`, the HUD dismiss.

But when I use `[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"test"]`, the hud can' show.

Can someone stay me why?

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [SVProgressHUD show]; 
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; 
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"test"]; 
       });
   }
```

Comment: please format your question.Instead of posting image plz post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SVProgressHUD.showInfoWithStatus` will hide the message after some time. so probably second HUD won't show cause it is still remove the first one.  `[SVProgressHUD show];`

If you wanna update don't call dismiss `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`

Comment: but the old version of SVProgressHUD don't have this issue, I read the source code, can't find any different between the new and old version

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

Use only:

```
[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"test"];
```

I think this is helpful for you.